# Backup photos and videos to Google Photos

Tags: google, google-photos

I am using the app download from https://photos.google.com/apps (*for Windows*)

My question, how do I make sure that when I delete uploaded photos/videos from the local folder it won't be deleted in Google Photos?

So for instance, I have this folder configured for sync with the app: `C:\Photos`
I dump photos and videos here and when the sync is complete I will need to permanently delete it from my hard disk to save space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a photo or video from your local device which is already backed-up to Google Photos, it won't be deleted from Google Photos.

To test this, backup any random photo or video to Google Photos, then delete it from local device. Now check Google Photos, you will see that photo or video there.

See the Notes on [Google Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?hl=en&ref_topic=6156061) page under **Set up the Backup and Sync computer app**:

> **Notes:**
>
> - If you remove a photo or video from your computer, it remains in Google Photos.
> - If you remove a photo or video from Google Photos, it's not removed from Google Drive or your computer.

Comment: I agree with your answer. In the past, if one synced Photos with Drive, the deletion happened everywhere. That does not happen anymore.

Comment: Maybe you can also help out https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/143525/sync-photos-and-videos-with-google-backup-and-sync-tool-for-windows