# Sync Photos and Videos with Google Backup and Sync tool for Windows

Tags: google, google-photos

I am using the Backup and Sync app from https://photos.google.com/apps
to backup my Photos and Videos to Google Photos, it works but the problem is I am uploading 1TB of photos and videos and the application stopped synching.

It says storage is full at *41 GB over 15 GB usage* when I check my Google Drive. I wonder why is this the case when Google Photos mentions from their website "Unlimited Free Storage"

My Google Drive, by the way, is empty, as I am just using my Google account for Google Photos. I even tried to install the same tool on a different computer to be able to sync the files that supposedly there consuming Google Drive space, and nothing was sync as expected, meaning my Google Drive is really empty.

How can I sync my Photos and Videos to Google Photos in this kind of situation?

**UPDATE**

I also have removed unsupported videos from `https://photos.google.com/u/1/unsupportedvideos` still the Google Drive "used space" doesn't go down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Google gives 15 GB free space to use, which includes Gmail, Photos and Drive.

To backup and sync your photos and videos in there are three options. Two options are unlimited free to sync and backup with reduced quality of photos and videos. Other one is free upto 15 GB with the original quality.

In you case I doubt you have select the original quality option, and that is the reason it shows you have used your storage.

[Learn about your backup options](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

Also check [Unsupported videos](https://photos.google.com/unsupportedvideos)
 under setting of Google people. This might taking lot of space.

Comment: Even if the Google Drive is empty, no files?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone experiencing the same problem, **the answer is to remove unsupported videos from Google Photos**, apparently, if you upload a video that Google Photos cannot process it will take up space regardless you enable the "High Quality" sync settings.

The way to remove unsupported videos is through a link like this:
https://photos.google.com/u/1/unsupportedvideos

(It took a while to update the storage used after removing the unsupported videos, so wait a bit)